# Boot configuration Data error during PXE boot after add VMware drivers

Tags: pxe-boot, wds, mdt

I have WDS and MDT installed on a Windows Server in my network. The WDS server is on the same subnet as the client machine. I am getting the following error on my VMware VMs when trying to boot LiteTouch over PXE:

[image]

I can't figure out how to get rid of the error. I've tried:

1. Recreating the LiteTouch boot image in MDT and re-importing it into WDS.
2. Rebooting the WDS/MDT server multiple times.
3. Switching the client VM's adapter type between `E1000E` and `VMXNET3`.
4. Deleting and remounting the hard drive on the VM.

Any other ideas on what I should do to troubleshoot?

Comment: This issue appears to be limited to VMware VMs only. I am able to boot physical servers from WDS/MDT without an issue.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by add drivers? Did the drivers get added to the Boot profile or did they just get added to the drivers folder only? Also can you see what the path is for your BCD on the servers that are booting? I wanna see if it is the same one for both VM and Server.

Comment: Also, why are you not just VMDK deploying the VMs? It will be faster and be less complex if you have a pre-built base OS and just use SCCM to add customizations after initial boot.

Comment: Within MDT I imported VMXNET3 drivers from `C:\Program Files\Common Files\VMware\Drivers\vmxnet3\Win8` of a VM with the VMware tools installed. Then, I regenerated the LiteTouch boot image, and import the WIM into WDS.

Comment: I'm not using a VMDK because I have an automated process that each night rebuilds the image (with the latest MS patches). The automated process exports the latest capture and imports it into MDT, ready for new deployments during the business day. The reason we developed this process is that it allows us to quickly provision PCs over PXE/MDT without having to wait for a Task Sequence to download and install patches released since the golden image was initially created. We're rebuilding the image using a VM, which is why I've opened this question asking for help with VMs.

Comment: This process worked flawlessly in another network (no shared resources). Since moving it over to our new network, we've been running into these issues. It looks like there is something wrong with the WDS installation. Would you agree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue appears to be WDS, not MDT.

My fix was to use a different PXE server to boot the LiteTouch boot image.